# Android studio: How to cast a png from drawable to sql database?

Tags: android, sql

So I have a jpg file in my drawable and I need to add it to a SQL database. To do so I tried this code:

```
try {
    File file = new File("res/drawable/user.jpg");
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] imgbyte = new byte[fs.available()];
    fs.read(imgbyte);
    contentValues.put("photo", imgbyte);
    fs.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
long ins = db.insert(database.getTableNameProfiles(), null, contentValues);
```

The element isn't added to the database, and the progamm catch the exception (I'm not sure of that but if I remove the "return false" the others input in my database function correctly).
I have no problem adding others elements to my database and the error seems to come from the FileInputStream method. Am I doing this right? 
Here is the creation of the database table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILES = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_NAME_PROFILES + "(" + KEY_PROFILES_USERNAME
    + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_PROFILES_PASSWORD
    + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PROFILES_MAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
    + KEY_PROFILES_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PROFILES_FIRSTNAME
    + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_PROFILES_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
    + KEY_PROFILES_SIZE + " TEXT," + KEY_PROFILES_PHOTO + " BLOB)";
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PROFILES);
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: You're saying that you have a png file in drawable, but you're using .jpg when creating file. And the return false causes the method to return, which is why your insert line wasn't getting executed when an exception was caught.

Comment: Post the error logs.

Comment: Noooooo... why do people insist on storing images in SQL? SQL is not made for storing large blobs of data, it's primarily for text. Store the image on the filesystem and put the path to the file in the database instead. However, I'm pretty sure you cannot access files in the Drawable folders like that, you need to retrieve it with a Context or put the image in an Assets folder instead.

Comment: Sorry it's a jpg file, I will correct it in the question.

Comment: Post the error logsss.